# Passing a variable to a variable within a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I'm grabbing a value from the registry assigning it to `%%b` and trying to pass `%%b` to another area within the batch file as shown below.

But it comes out as `%b`.

It does not pass the variable a second time:

```bash
Set SN=reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\XXXXXX Systems\XXXXXaway" /v "SerialNumber"
```

Does not work obviously.

Here's my code:

```bash
 @echo off
 
For /F "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\XXXXXX Systems\XXXXXaway" /v "SerialNumber"') do echo %%b
    
"c:\program files (x86)\carefusion\RSS Component Manager\Tools\atlas.DeviceRegistration.exe" environment=SQE serialnumber=%%b displayname=%computername% "devicetype=XXXXXX 2" "sapshipto=27703"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without wanting to be repetitive, but what happens inside the `For` loop is valid inside the loop, unless you define it inside the `For` loop for use inside or outside the loop.

But it may also occur to save before your `For` loop for use within the `For` loop.

See what this second option would be like applied in your context:

```bash
@echo off 

set "_Query=Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\XXXXXX Systems\XXXXXaway" /v "SerialNumber""
set "_Atlas="%Programfiles(x86)%\carefusion\RSS Component Manager\Tools\atlas.DeviceRegistration.exe""
set "_arg's=environment=SQE serialnumber=^%%~b displayname=%computername% "devicetype=XXXXXX 2" "sapshipto=27703""

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('%_Query%') do %_Atlas% %_arg's%
```

---

**Note**  In your example, Skip=2 is present, which I don't know if it is really relevant/necessary, unless your query returns 3 lines and the one of interest is the third (and last line)

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
  - **[`CMD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**
  - **[`For Loop`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[`For /D Loop`](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
  - **[`For /R Loop`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

Answer (score 0):

`%%b` is only valid inside the FOR loop.

You should replace `echo %%b` by `set var=%%b`,
then use `%var%` in the following code.

You may put `echo %var%` after the FOR loop to verify
its value.